# Pumpkin Nitro Mousse?

Tags: equipment, whipped-cream, mousse

I want to make little pumpkin mousse brûlée deserts, and I also want to play with my new whipped cream dispenser. Do you think pumpkin purée would do bad things to my dispenser?

I swear I've seen TV chefs doing stuff like this, but they don't actually pay for any of their equipment so I doubt they care much if they ruin something to get a result. I don't have a production company buying my kitchen toys though, so thought I'd see if anyone has tried this and maybe I can learn from your mistakes/success.

Comment: What brand is your whipped cream dispenser? Does it come with a user manual? Does the user manual provide recommendations about substances you should (or should not) use in the dispenser? Even if none of them is specifically pumpkin puree, it may help to see what other sorts of substances should work.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you can put through a fine mesh strainer will likely not be too much of a problem in a whipper.  In fact, the [ISI website has a recipe for pumpkin mousse.](https://www.isi.com/en/culinary/recipes/detail/sweet-pumpkin-mousse-with-chocolate-and-hazelnut-brownie/) You should find lots of advice on the web, as this technique was quite popular for a few years.